# Listar dados de um JSON com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estou tentando listar os dados de um JSON através do JavaScript, porém ele só apresenta na listagem a **posição 0**.

Abaixo segue o JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"23"
   },
   {
      "id":"24"
  }
]
```

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo que é um retorno de uma requisição AJAX:

```
success: function(getApi) {


  for (var i = 0; i < getApi.length; i++) {
    var id = getApi[i].id;


    var dados = '<li class="list-group-item">' +
      '<a href="#" class="media shadow-15">' +
      '<div class="w-auto h-100">' +
      '<figure class="avatar avatar-40"><img src="img/espaco.jpg" alt=""> </figure>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="media-body">' +
      '<h5 class=" mb-0">' + id + '</h5>' +
      '<p><span class="badge mb-1">Teste</span></p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</a>' +
      '</li> ';

    $(".resultApi").html(dados);
  }
}
```

Como faço para mostrar todos os **ID**s do meu JSON?

Comment: No começo da sua função coloque um `console.log(getApi);` e coloque o resultado disso na sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar jQuery para chamar seu arquivo json para exibir sua lista completa.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function dadosJson() {
    $.getJSON('dados.json', function(json) {
        $.each(json, function() {
            let info = '<p>' + this['id'] + '</p>';
            $('#boxTeste').append(info);
        });
    });/*GetJson end*/ 
}/*function end*/ 

    dadosJson();

});
```

`$.getJSON` irá buscar seu arquivo com o `json`, a função `.each` irá percorre o seu arquivo json buscando os parametros 'id' e exibindo eles ao cria-los através da function `.append(info)` dentro do da `div` especifica

Answer (score 5):

É porque você está usando `.html()` quando deveria usar `.append()`. O `.html()` irá substituir o HTML do elemento alvo a cada iteração no `for`, resultando apenas o código da última volta do `for`. Deveria ser:

```
$(".resultApi").append(dados);
```

Verifique também se `dados` é um JSON parseado (provavelmente é). Se não será preciso incluir no seu Ajax a opção:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Creio que o fato do `dados` ser um JSON já está implícito na pergunta, tendo em vista que se fosse um JSON em string, o `getApi[i].id` estaria produzindo um erro, que não foi mencionado na pergunta.

Comment: Verdade Felipe... só coloquei mesmo com um add-on na resposta... Na verdade nem daria erro, daria "undefined" :D

Comment: "Melhor ter e não precisar do que precisar e não ter" xD

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. :)

Comment: @Sam mais uma da série: "aconteceu comigo". Pior que comigo eu fiz um p#†@ trampo e o cara teve resposta aceita com 3 linhas de resposta. E o foco da minha resposta era justamente o que ele tinha "copiado e mudado as palavras". 

Comment: @sam, muito obrigado! resolveu o meu problema amigo.

Comment: @Sam, na verdade, eu comecei a escrever a resposta antes de você enviar a sua. A sua resposta pode até ter sido postada antes, mas garanto que não a copiei. :/

Comment: @LuizFelipe Tranquilo. Isso já aconteceu mt comigo. Acho que as duas respostas acrescentam.

Answer (score 5):

O seu problema é que você está **redefinindo** o HTML do item após cada iteração (*loop*). Isso fará com que somente o **último** ID do *array* seja mostrado, já que todos os anteriores foram redefinidos pela iteração seguinte.

Desse modo, ao invés de **redefinir** o conteúdo, você deve simplesmente **acrescentar** os dados gerados em cada iteração aos dados previamente criados.

---

Veja o seu **problema** em um exemplo um pouco mais simples:

```js
const $list = $('#my-list')
const ids = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  const id = ids[i].id
  const html = `<li>${id}</li>`
  
  console.log('ID atual:', id, ' | HTML atual:', html)
  
  // Note que, ao invés de você acrescentar o HTML gerado ao final da lista,
  // você simplesmente está redefinindo todo o HTML definido anteriormente,
  // ao usar o método .html().
  $list.html(html)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my-list"></ul>
```

Para resolver isso, como mencionado anteriormente, você precisa **acrescentar** o HTML gerado ao **final** da lista. Para isso, vamos recorrer ao método [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) do jQuery. Assim:

```js
const $list = $('#my-list')
const ids = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  const id = ids[i].id
  const html = `<li>${id}</li>`
  
  console.log('ID atual:', id, ' | HTML atual:', html)
  
  // Agora, ao invés de redefinir o HTML após cada iteração, estamos simplesmente
  // acrescentando o HTML gerado ao conteúdo, já existente, da lista:
  $list.append(html)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my-list"></ul>
```

---

Desse modo, no seu código, você deve trocar o `html` (que substitui o HTML já existente por um novo HTML) pelo `append` (que acrescenta um novo HTML a um HTML já existente). De:

```
$(".resultApi").html(dados);
```

Para:

```
$(".resultApi").append(dados);
```

Comment: Luiz Felipe, agradeço muito pela solução. Resolveu o meu problema e tirou uma grande dúvida que tinha do append. Muito obrigado!